# Stop JavaScript Popup From Activating Every Looped Icon Until Individually Clicked

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm pretty new to this and would greatly appreciate any help you might have. I have created a popup to display additional details when an icon is clicked. I have multiple cards with the icon which display different details pertaining to the given card. The icon is only visible on mouseenter. The popup is working on click, and it closes upon being clicked again. The issue is that when one icon is clicked, it is activating all of the icons. If it is not re-clicked to close, the popups for each card become visible on mouseenter.

I am trying to only activate the clicked icon while leaving the others closed until selected.

Here is my popup:

```
<div class="sponsor-index--PopUp" onclick="sponsorPop()">
   <button class="sponsor-index--iconBtnMini">
      <i id="details" class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x"></i>
   </button>
   <span class="sponsor-index--PopUpText">
      <span class="sponsor-index--details">
         <strong>Name:</strong><br /> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)<br />
         <strong>Dimensions</strong><br /> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Photo.OriginalWidth) x 
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Photo.OriginalHeight) (Width x Height)<br />
         <strong>Link:</strong><br /> <a href="@item.Link" target="_blank">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
            item.Link)</a>
       </span>
   </span>
</div>
```

Here is my script:

```
<script>
//Pop up for details icon
function sponsorPop() {
   var popup = document.getElementsByClassName("sponsor-index--PopUpText");

   for (let i = 0; i < popup.length; i += 1) {
      popup.item(i).classList.toggle("show");
      }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the clicked DIV as an argument to the function, and then search for the icon within the DIV.

```
div class="sponsor-index--PopUp" onclick="sponsorPop(this)">
   <button class="sponsor-index--iconBtnMini">
      <i id="details" class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x"></i>
   </button>
   <span class="sponsor-index--PopUpText">
      <span class="sponsor-index--details">
         <strong>Name:</strong><br /> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)<br />
         <strong>Dimensions</strong><br /> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Photo.OriginalWidth) x 
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Photo.OriginalHeight) (Width x Height)<br />
         <strong>Link:</strong><br /> <a href="@item.Link" target="_blank">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
            item.Link)</a>
       </span>
   </span>
</div>
```

```
<script>
//Pop up for details icon
function sponsorPop(div) {
    var popup = div.querySelector(".sponsor-index--PopUpText");
    if (popup) {
        popup.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
</script>
```